# How to handle (on the server side) ampersand while inserting text into MySQL using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, ios, escaping, ampersand

When we insert a string with ampersand character into mysql, the string is inserted only till & character is encountered.

Example: when inserting "one & two"... only "one " is inserted.

Tried a few things like... htmlentities OR htmlspecialchars... nothing working for me.

Current PHP code:

```
$sms = htmlentities($_POST["sms"]);


$query = "INSERT INTO sms (detail,catID,deviceID) VALUES ('".$sms."',".$_POST["catID"].",'".$_POST["deviceID"]."')";
```

And as the app is live... I need to resolve it by editing the PHP files only, on the server. (I hope it can be done)

Comment: What is a sample value of $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA?

Comment: The first mistake is not sanitizing user input, especially with code that's live. `mysql_real_escape_string` is your friend. Treat all user input as if it was a deadly disease.

Comment: What it says `echo $_POST["sms"]`? I doubt that post does not have string part after &

Comment: Hello [Bobby tables](http://xkcd.com/327/). Your code is insecure. Take the app OFFLINE, fix the errors and the insecure code. Stop whining about urgent and stuff, we are not here to get ordered.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder - thanks... but it did not work... I had tried that earlier too...

Comment: @Rajat Bansal I know it won't fix your problem. But it will prevent SQL inserts from destroying your DB. Right now, anyone can insert, delete, update, or do whatever they want with your DB. That is a much bigger problem then some encoding discrepancy between PHP and MySQL.

Comment: @Shef +1 for a good 'ol Bobby tables reference :)

Comment: @PhpMyCoder - Oh... I get it! Thanks mate! very valuable... I am poor at php.

Comment: @Ragat Bansal Don't sweat it. Every day (even for advanced coders) is a learning experience. Just make sure before going live with sites that you have considered every vulnerability. Do some research on MySQL injections, XSS, and CSRF to make sure your live site (and any future ones) aren't vulnerable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, well to complete the discussion, couldn't found a server side only solution... requires modification at both client & server side.

Here's how I needed to pass the upload text (as newStr):

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:30];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *newStr = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
                                                                               NULL,
                                                                               (CFStringRef)uploadText.text,
                                                                               NULL,
                                                                               (CFStringRef)@"&",
                                                                               kCFStringEncodingUTF8 );

NSString *parameters = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"sms=%@&catID=%d&deviceID=%@",newStr,webCatID,[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]];

[newStr release];
```

And this modification on the server side:

```
    if ( get_magic_quotes_gpc() )
{
    $_POST['sms'] = stripslashes($_POST['sms'] );
}

$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO sms (detail,catID,deviceID) VALUES ('%s', '%d', '%s')",
                 mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sms']),
                 ((int) $_POST['catID']),
                 mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['deviceID']));
```

Special thx to @PhpMyCoder & @Shef

& LOL on the urgency!

Comment: And now I think using [asihttprequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) is much better way to go!
It takes care of all such problems itself

Answer (score 2):

Here is a secure (against SQL injection) query:

```
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO sms (detail,catID,deviceID) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s')",
                 mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sms']),
                 mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['catID']),
                 mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['deviceID']));
```

I am escaping everything as a string, because I don't know your table schema.

However, if `catID` and `deviceID` are `INTEGER` types, then it should be:

```
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO sms (detail,catID,deviceID) VALUES ('%s', %d, %d)",
                 mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sms']),
                 ((int) $_POST['catID']),
                 ((int) $_POST['deviceID']));
```

Comment: still didn't work... can there be any sort of encoding issue?

Comment: @Rajat: add this code somewhere (don't do it on a live server) and show us what the out is: `var_dump($_POST["sms"])`.

Comment: `string(4) "one "` for "one & two".

Comment: @Rajat: The issue is somewhere else. How do you submit the form, do you use ajax?

Comment: No ajax used. For var_dump I used a test PHP which I was using for self-resolving the issue prior to asking ques here. It is a simple php file just echoing out variable populated using GET Method... This echo out has been giving me same issue, so I think if I can resolve here, can resolve on live too... or I am wrong here? Thanks for your ongoing help though!

Comment: Also, would like to mention that if I literally replace $sms with "one & two", it works perfect! just in case if it gives some idea where the prob could be

Comment: The problem is that you are using `$_GET` to test your code dude!!! The ampersand `&` is used to separate URL parameters. You must encode the URL variables before you can use them in a URL. Do _not_ test the application via `$_GET` variables. Build up the form just like on the live server, and post from there to test it.

Answer (score 0):

`htmlentities();` function is best used when displaying data from the database or a POST to protect the user and page form XSS

When inserting into the database sanitize to protect the database from abuse, using `mysql_real_escape_string()`:

```
if(isset($_POST)){
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $value=stripslashes($value);
        }
        $_POST[$key]=mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    }
}

$query = "INSERT INTO sms (detail,catID,deviceID) VALUES ('".$sms."',".$_POST["catID"].",'".$_POST["deviceID"]."')";
```

Comment: Why oh why on earth would you escape everything? :D